# Types of regression that might work on small samples

Tags: regression, sample-size

I know that this kind of discussion might be both a silly...very silly and a hot issue simultaneously...but I thought it would be nice to raise it : Which types of linear AND non-linear regression could be recommended when you have a small sample size (e.g. 50-70 records) and you want to predict a continuous outcome from 5-7 predictors (both categorical and continuous). Can k-fold cross-validated stepwise linear regression OR Partial Least Regression be a remedy to this problem? Are boosted trees OR Neural networks just insane even to think about them? Your responses are GREATLY WELCOMED and VERY MUCH APPRECIATED.

THANK YOU!

Comment: This doesn't really deserve to be an answer but part of it is gonna be: what is (in) your data? Because best case a regular OLS will do. Worst case nothing will do. It really will entail a throughout investigation though, as the asymptotic shortcuts cannot be made. So I guess a start would be to check ye olde OLS assumptions first. I think you can guess whre this is going.

Comment: You don't select the regression method based on the sample size, you select the regression method based on the dependent variable and your research questions.

Comment: So...Indeed my question was silly. I can admit knowing that it would not make it any better :) With respect to the research question: Testing the predicting ability of these 5 independent variables with reference to the continuous outcome/variable (e.g. attitude)...but I still think...that (sample) size always matter unfortunately...as far as "IMA" kind response...yes now I have a better idea where this is going...THANK YOU! P.S. of course any other additional ideas/views from other members are always welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

For a simple linear regression model with 1 covariate, I've heard the rule of thumb being no less than 30 observations. However, this can be flexible depending on how well the data fits compared to a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution. But for discussion purposes, I recommend the following paper:

http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~ajw13/stat501/SpecialTopics/SampleSizes_MLR.pdf

Please refer to tables 1 and 2 in the paper.